# How to replace a Fragment with a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` where I have data and an Adapter to handle all the clicks. And I have a Fragment I want to load when an item is clicked from the `RecyclerView`. Now what I wanted is to replace the `RecyclerView` with the Fragment when an item is clicked from the same `Recycler View`.

I have tried this but it crashed with an Error

**Adapter**

```
holder.cvContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SingleContactFragment singleContactFragment = SingleContactFragment.newInstance(contact);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.rv_contact_list, singleContactFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

where **rv_contact_list** is the current RecyclerView.

The Error is

```
01-19 20:35:01.892 13088-13088/com.xzii.pkg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.xzii.pkg, PID: 13088
                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:3869)
                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3604)
                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3408)
```

Comment: Look this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695465/boolean-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerviewviewholder-shouldignore-on-a

Comment: To replace a fragment the RecyclerView should be also be a fragment. So your replace will be agains ta container, and not the component 'rv_c....'

Comment: Instead of recyclerview I'd give the container of the recyclerview . Ie layout which is recyclerview is declared

Answer (score 0):

The error basically complains "out of context data" assigned to the adaptor of the RecyclerView. Try to set the adaptor to null and remove it then add the new fragment. Only got a Kotlin example code now.

```
val topicListFragment:TopicListFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.topicListFragment) as TopicListFragment
topicListFragment.removeAdaptor()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(topicListFragment).commit()
val topicFragment = TopicFragment()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.homeContent, topicFragment).commit()
```

You may do not need to remove the fragment anymore after empty the adaptor, the logcat shows

> RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout