# how to add new view to recycleview dynamically?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I'm using Recylerview to display my items. On button click i have to add complete new layout to the top the recycleview.

I've searched a lot but all I could find was about adding same layout (we used in recycleview adapter) with different values to recycleview dynamically.

I know about **adapter.notifyItemChanged()**. SO i know how to add data to my list but i have confusion about how to add that different view to desired position in recycleview.

What I've tried:

```
linear_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_folder, null);

        TextView tv_user_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_folder);
        tv_user_name.setText(edt_folder.getText().toString());
        rv_stamps.addView(v, 0);
    }
});
```

But I'm getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:3895)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3630)
```

Comment: you can add view by adding value to your recyclerview array list

Comment: Add the item to the dataList in position 0 and call `adapter.notifyItemInserted(0)`

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695465/boolean-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerviewviewholder-shouldignore-on-a?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @DivyeshPatel but my adapter's xml and my new xml is different .. if i'd just add data and notify adapter , it would add to old xml not new ..

Comment: for that you need to use @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 2;
    }  in adapter

Comment: @DivyeshPatel  so i have to set my adapters xml according to that int . right ?

Comment: yes return  number for your postion and in Createviewholder method inflate layout as per viewType

Comment: @DivyeshPatel  ok thanks divyesh , i'll try it out and let you know